# If $A+B+C+D=0$ such that $A,B,C,D$ are points on a unit circle, then the points form a rectangle (geometric proof)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

This question is from Needhams "Visual Complex Analysis" and I'm having trouble understanding the proof in a solution I found.  I also know that this question has been posted before but I want to understand the geometric proof.

Specifacally, I don't see how in the first line they get that $P,O,Q$ lie in a straight line?  Earlier, there was the question which asked us to show that the points that satisfy $|z-a|=|z-b|$, for fixed complex numbers $a,b$, all lie on a straight line.  But thinking back to that didn't help me to understand how they got $P,O,Q$ to lie in a straight line provided that $|P|=|Q|$.

Thanks

**Proof**

[image]

Comment: I don't think four points can form a triangle. ;-)

Comment: Maybe the OP means a rectangle?

Comment: @Dog_69 It is rectangle (see the last line in the proof).

Comment: oops lol  I rushed when writing the title

Comment: As Needham says, it's because $P=-Q$.

Comment: In fact $(P+Q)/2=0$ means that $O$ is the midpoint of $PQ$.